# Vector space addition commutative axiom proof

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

$$F = \left \{  (x,y,z) \in R^{3}: x+y+z = 1\right \}$$ with addition and multiplication defined as:
$$(x,y,z) \boxplus (u,v,w) = (x+u-1, y+v, z+w)$$
$$a \boxdot (x,y,z) = (ax - a + 1, ay, az)$$
$$\forall (x,y,z), \space (u,v,w) \in F; \space \forall a \in \mathbb{R}$$

Show that F, with this operations, is a vector space under the real numbers.

I tried to check if the defined addition respects the commutative axiom.
$$(x,y,z) \boxplus (u,v,w) = (x+u-1, y+v, z+w) = (u+x-1, v+y, w+z) = (u,v,w) \boxplus (x,y,z) $$

I'm not sure if this is correct.

Comment: that looks correct

Comment: @J.W.Tanner would it be correct if I did something like this:
$$(x+u-1, y+v, z+w) = (x+u, y+v, z+w)  + (-1, 0, 0) = (u+x, v+y, w+z) + (-1, 0, 0) = (u+x-1, v+y, w+z)$$

Comment: yes, but I don't know why you would bother with that; you could say $\vec a \boxplus \vec b=\vec a + \vec b + (-1,0,0)$, so $\vec b\boxplus \vec a=\vec b + \vec a + (-1,0,0) = \vec a + \vec b + (-1,0,0)= \vec a \boxplus \vec b$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner You'r right, it makes no sense.
I'm having troubles dealing with the axiom of the additions neutral element axiom:
$$(x,y,z) + (1, 0, 0) = (x+1-1,y+0,z+0) = (x,y,z)$$ Is (1, 0, 0) the additions neutral element?

Comment: $(1,0,0)$ is the neutral element for $\boxplus:$  $(x,y,z)\boxplus(1,0,0)=(x,y,z)$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner
So we can also say that:
$$(x,y,z) \boxplus (-x+2, -y, -z) = (x+(-x+2)-1, y-y, z-z) = (1, 0, 0)$$ where (-x+2, -y, -z) is the additive inverse?